# Вопрос от новичка

Tags: html, bash, таблицы

Есть файл формата txt где попеременно идут строчки:

```
1*name*
2*ip*
3*name*
4*ip*
5*name*
6*ip*
и т.д.
```

Имена и ip есесно разные, требуется сделать веб страницу вот такого вида:

```
Имя    ip
name   ip
```

подскажите алгоритм куда копать, умею только немного в баш.

Comment: веб страница это понятие оооочень растяжимое, посмотрите по меткам, добавил пока только html, может чего-то ещё более точное найдете для себя

Comment: Если реализовать парсер можно на любом ЯП, отпишите в [телеграмм](https://t.me/CzarOfScripts)

Comment: Какой вопрос то?

Comment: У вас проблема с чтением строк в bash-е или форматрованием текста html-страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Пусть есть текстовый файл `input.txt` следующего вида:

```
name1
ip1
name2
ip2
name3
ip3
```

Можно написать скрипт `generate.sh` на bash, который в цикле будет брать каждые две строчки из файла и из них формировать строки таблицы html:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 [FILE]"
  exit 1
fi

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>"
echo "<html>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<title>Table</title>"
echo "</head>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<table>"
echo "  <tr>"
echo "    <th>Имя</th>"
echo "    <th>ip</th>"
echo "  </tr>"
while read -r name && read -r ip; do
  echo "  <tr>"
  echo "    <td>$name</td>"
  echo "    <td>$ip</td>"
  echo "  </tr>"
done <"$1"
echo "</table>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

Делаем скрипт исполняемым:

```bash
chmod +x generate.sh
```

И запускаем так:

```bash
./generate.sh input.txt > output.html
```